# How to use void when using conditional types

Tags: typescript

The props' type is correctly inferred as `void`, but it only works if I pass `undefined` as an argument.

Is it possible not to pass anything as an argument??

```
const openModal = <T>(
  modal: (props:T) => void,
  props: {} extends Omit<T, "onClose"> ? void : Omit<T, "onClose">
) => {
  return;
};

const ModalOne = (props: {onClose: () => void}) => {
    return;
}

const ModalTwo = (props: {text: string, onClose: () => void}) => {
    return;
}

openModal(ModalOne) // not working (Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. An argument for 'props' was not provided.)

openModal(ModalOne, {}) // not working (Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'.)

openModal(ModalOne, undefined) // working

openModal(ModalTwo, {text: 'test'}) // working
```

Comment: props?: {} extends Omit<T, "onClose">  Question mark behind the parameter name to flag as option.

Comment: @ThomasRenger Thanks! However, if I specify props as an optional parameter, I don't have to pass the parameter even if I need to pass it.

Comment: I don't understand. It's either optional or required. It can't be both or none. You can either set it to be required and then you always have to pass it or you can set it to be optional and then you can pass it or not.

Comment: You've run into the bug at [ms/TS#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131). The workaround I normally use is to use a rest parameter instead, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7GVEN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic By using conditional types, I want to make sure that I pass a parameter or nothing.

Comment: @jcalz It seems to match my case exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of [the `void` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void) to make a [function parameter optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#27522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27522)) is unfortunately not fully supported.  It doesn't tend to work with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#29131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29131).  This is considered a bug in TypeScript, but it's been around for a long time with no sign that it will be fixed anytime soon or ever.  I'd recommend that you avoid using `void` for this reason (indeed `void` behaves weirdly enough in so many circumstances that you should probably always pause a little to be sure it's really what you want to use).

Instead, you can implement "possibly optional" function parameters by using a [rest parameter of a tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types), where the tuple type depends on whatever condition you want to check.  For example:

```
const openModal = <T,>(
    modal: (props: T) => void,
    ...[props]: {} extends Omit<T, "onClose"> ?
        [props?: Omit<T, "onClose">] :
        [props: Omit<T, "onClose">]
) => {
    return;
};
```

So technically `openModal` is a variadic function whose rest parameter `...[props]` is either of type `[props?: Omit<T, "onClose">]` (a one-element tuple whose element is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types)) or of type `[props: Omit<T, "onClose">]` (a one-element tuple whose element is required).  Since `...[props]` uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), then this ends up giving you a `props` parameter inside the function whose type is either `Omit<T, "onClose">` or `Omit<T, "onClose"> | undefined` depending on the type `T`.

When you call it, if the empty object type is assignable to `T`, then you can call `openModal()` with one argument. Otherwise two arguments are required:

```
const ModalOne = (props: { onClose: () => void }) => { };
openModal(ModalOne); // okay
openModal(ModalOne, {});// okay
openModal(ModalOne, undefined); // okay

const ModalTwo = (props: { text: string, onClose: () => void }) => { };
openModal(ModalTwo); // error 
openModal(ModalTwo, {}); // error
openModal(ModalTwo, undefined); // error
openModal(ModalTwo, { text: 'test' }); // okay

const ModalThree = (props: { text?: string, onClose: () => void }) => { };
openModal(ModalThree); // okay
openModal(ModalThree, {}); // okay
openModal(ModalThree, undefined); // okay
openModal(ModalThree, { text: 'test' }); // okay
```

Looks like the behavior you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QHA5MQ56h9XpxPOnX6w1QY2CsEp6hAA)